# How to grep return result as the matching term

Tags: terminal, grep, nstask

I would like to return only the first instance (case-insensitive) of the term I used to search (if there's a match), how would I do this?

example:

```
$ grep "exactly-this"

Binary file /Path/To/Some/Files/file.txt matches
```

I would like to return the result like:

```
$ grep "exactly-this"

exactly-this
```

Answer (score 0):

grep has an inbuilt count argument

You can use the `-m` option to give a count argument to grep

```
grep -m 1 "exactly-this"
```

If you want to avoid the message in case of the binary files,use

```
grep -a -m 1 "exactly-this"
```

Note that this will print the `word` in which the match occurred.Since it is a binary file,the `word` may span over multiple lines

Comment: It doesn't output `exactly-this`.

Comment: you mean you want to know how to match the exact string too?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the `-o` option of `grep`.

From the `man page`

```
 -o, --only-matching
             Prints only the matching part of the lines.
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
This is a file with some exactly this in the middle
with exactly this in the begining
and some at the very end in brackets (exactly this)

[jaypal:~/Temp] grep -o 'exactly this' file
exactly this
exactly this
exactly this

[jaypal:~/Temp] grep -om1 'exactly this' file
exactly this
```